# How do I install a new version of Eclipse on an older Linux as non-root?

Tags: software-installation, suse, eclipse, non-root-user

I have a non-root account on an older SUSE Linux machine (from around 2012).

Is it possible for me to install a recent version of Eclipse (e.g. from 2019), for myself, on this machine? If it is, what would I need to do, other than download and decompress Eclipse itself? I'm assuming I will be missing some dependencies, perhaps a more recent version of the Java Runtime Environment or some libraries.

Comment: Why downloading and untarring Eclipse is a problem?

Comment: @schaiba: ... but note that Eclipse won't work if you just download, untar and run it.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need the following:

- Your Eclipse download package or the Eclipse installer.
- A relatively recent JDK (hopefully the most recent would do), from [here](https://jdk.java.net/13/)
- The GTK3 libraries.

You probably don't have the latter, and you're not root, and let's not assume a relevant binary package is available, so - you'll have to build GTK3. To do so, you'll need:

- The GTK3 library sources - from [here](https://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php).
- A bunch of associated library/package sources,  from the same location:

  - glib
  - atk
  - pango
  - gdk-pixbuf
  - GObject-introspection
- Additional packages libraries, with appropriate minimum version versions:

  - fribidi
  - cairo
  - cairo-gobject

Let's hope those don't have further unsatisfied dependencies on your system.

Also, you're likely to find sources compressed with the `xz` tool. You might not have it, and your `tar` may not support it. Look for an online converter, or get:

- The `xz` utility, from [here](https://tukaani.org/xz/)